# How to remove the default tooltip and keep my own tooltip's content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a tooltip with jQuery but the default browser was still there. I got it away with this script, but it also makes the content of my own tooltip dissapear, wich is the title of some images on the page:

```
$('#imagerow img').hover(

function () {
 $(this).data('tooltipText', $(this).attr('title'));
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
},

function () {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title'));
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tooltipText'));

});
```

Click on the smaller images in #imagerow to see. Here's a link to the page in progress:

http://www.beijerland.website/gallerij.html

Can someone help me to get my own tooltip content back? (without displaying the default tooltip) Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#imagerow img').hover(

function () {
 $(this).attr('data-tooltipText', $(this).attr('title'));
 $(this).removeAttr('title');
},

function () {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('data-tooltipText'));
});
```